# Is there a column width bug in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

In a Google spreadsheet when I change the column width to 25 I noticed it looked very narrow.  So I saved it as an .xlsx and then opened it in Excel. There it shows a column width of less than 3 as I suspected. That is a tiny column width.

Having done a little testing, here is the equivalence table I get:

```
Google spreadsheets col width    |    Excel col width    |  ratio
20                                    2.22                  9.01
30                                    3.67                  8.17
40                                    5.11                  7.83
50                                    6.56                  7.62
```

What on Earth is going on?

Comment: What happen if instead of 25 you change the column width to 24, 26 or 30? By the way, I'm not able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rubén I updated the question with some more figures. I am confused why you can't reproduce it. Do you mean that if you have a Google spreadsheet, set the col width to 25 and export it as .xlsx file, it shows col width of 25 in Excel for you?

Comment: The first statement says that setting column with to 25 sets the column very narrow. From my point of view 25 isn't very narrow so I didn't tried to download the spreadsheet as .xlsx.

Comment: @Rubén Ah ok. It would very interesting if you can reproduce any of the figures I put in the question. I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind that Google Sheets use pixels to set the column width instead of "points of scale" used by Excel.

NOTE: I used [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing-tool.html) to measure a column with. You could do the same by using any tool to measure a screen area.

Reference

- [Description of how column widths are determined in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/es-mx/help/214123/description-of-how-column-widths-are-determined-in-excel)