# How tell Google Sheets to not change columns width?

Tags: google-sheets, microsoft-excel

I wrote a script that generates excel files. In those files, I add images inside cells. I set the width of the images cell by calculating the total images width.

Here is how it looks in MS Excel:

[image]

And here's how it looks in Google Sheets (same file):
[image]

As you can see, the width of the cell is smaller than the image in Google Docs, but in MS Excel it's the correct size.

Looking at she `sheet1.xml` of the original file, I can see:

```
<cols>
    <col min="1" max="1" width="10" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="2" max="2" width="10" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="3" max="3" width="12.1" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="4" max="4" width="20.050541516245488" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="5" max="5" width="10" customWidth="1"/>
    <col min="6" max="6" width="14.3" customWidth="1"/>
</cols>
```

And in the new file (after uploading to google, I downloaded it as `xlsx`) I see:

```
<cols>
    <col customWidth="1" min="1" max="2" width="7.78"/>
    <col customWidth="1" min="3" max="3" width="9.44"/>
    <col customWidth="1" min="4" max="4" width="15.56"/>
    <col customWidth="1" min="5" max="5" width="7.78"/>
    <col customWidth="1" min="6" max="6" width="11.11"/>
    <col customWidth="1" min="7" max="26" width="8.33"/>
</cols>
```

Google changed the column sizes. Why, and how can I solve this?

Links:

- [Original `xlsx` file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6Ph4MYE5ljC96nIlmyGznz-O07WQI3i/view?usp=sharing)
- [New file by Google Docs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BVM_HtsVXf0_0WWz-lvYtb6Ws4ypAqgV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How are you converting the xlsx file to Google Sheets format?

Comment: @Rubén uploading it to drive or even just viewing the `xlsx` file via an android device.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The above is because

1. Google Sheets and Microsoft Excel use different unit of measure to set the cell dimensions. See [Is there a column width bug in Google sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121109/88163)
2. There are some known issues i.e. 1) [Sheet.getRowHeight() and Sheet.getColumnWidth() report wrong sizes](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761787) 2) [Google Apps Script Sheets getRowHeight() only returns the correct height when a row height is specified, does not work with Text wrap](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122241618).
   that might be related
3. There is no way for end-users to change the way that Google convert Excel files to Google Sheets format

One workaround is to make another script that replicates what is done by the script that you use to creates the Excel but to create the Google Sheets spreadsheet.

Another workaround might be to use Google Apps Script to adjust the columns sizes.

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why is it getting converted wrong? If they use a different unit of measure when they convert the `xlsx` file, shoulldn't it still be the correct size?

Comment: @HTMHell That is something that only Google can answer.